# neo4j resultSet to JSON node and edge lists

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm struggling with this problem in days, there is an easy way to covert a result of a neo4j query in Spring Data Neo4j (types `Iterable<Map<String, String>>` or `Iterable<Map<String, Object>>`, I guess) in a plain JSON list of nodes and edges for the visualization in a browser using a javascript library?
It looks so dumb as question, and yet I find nothing about it..

I tried to fits this code to my data model, https://github.com/jexp/sdn-boot-example/blob/master/src/main/java/movies/spring/data/neo4j/services/MovieService.java but that code is domain specific.
Since I have multiple node entities and multiple relationship entities, it would be crazy write a class ad-hoc each combination of node and edge.
The only thing so far it works is reformat the data clientside, which I don't like that much.

Comment: Any more information on code,  data model and things you have tried so far?

Comment: edited my question. I can't believe there isn't a pretty standard way to do that..there is something i'm missing

Comment: _for the visualization in a browser using a javascript library_ - there are many libraries with many different formats, it does not make sense to create a converter for every one of them.

Comment: usually javascript libraries use an array of nodes + an array of edges as datasource. But besides how this structure is common, there is a way I can convert a neo4j-ogm pattern result to this structure?